# Пытаюсь создать кнопку, которая при загрузке страницы будет неактивной в течении 3-х минут

Tags: javascript, html

Суть в следующем, на странице загадка, форма для ответа(текстом), кнопка ответить и хотелось бы реализовать еще одну кнопку "Подсказка" которая при загрузке страницы будет неактивной 3 минуты.
Не могу разобраться как сделать кнопку неактивной при загрузке страницы.
Прошу помощи у профессионалов, заранее спасибо!

```
<div> 
<button id="btn" onClick="Answear()">Подсказка</button> 
</div> 
<script> 
function Answear() {
var btn = document.getElementById('btn'); 
alert('Шпион'); 
btn.classList.add('disabled'); 
setTimeout(function() {
btn.classList.add('disabled'); }, 180000); 
}
</script>
```

Comment: Добавь в вопрос код, как ты пытаешься и что конкретно не получается

Comment: во-первых  я написал "добавить **в вопрос**", во-вторых я писал **что конкретно не получается**

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, прошу прощения, исправился. проверьте пожалуйста!

Comment: Чтобы сделать кнопку неактивнойц при загрузке страницы, надо либо просто вызывать метод `Answear()`  после загрузке html либо вызывать клик на кнопке  программно (в данном случае проще всего первое)